# Onclick event sends parameter, if click is not provided set default parameter

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send parameters by using event onlick. But I also want to set default parameter if user did't click.

```
<script>
function getItems(value, object) {
    var parametar = object.innerHTML=value; //receive parameter
    //then I send parameter to API
</script>
```

Script above on click displays parameter. But I want to set parameter 1 if user did not make click. If users click parameter will change.

```
 <div class="vertical-menu">
        <div class="col-12">
          <a onclick="getItems('1', this)" class="active">Item1 <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
          <a href="" onclick="getItems('2', this)">Item2 <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
          <a href="" onclick="getItems('3', this)">Item3<i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
          <a href="" onclick="getItems('4', this)">Item4<i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
          <a href="" onclick="getItems('5', this)">Item5<i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
         </div>                      
    </div>
```

Comment: How do you want to execute getItems other then on click?

Comment: I was wondering if is possible to do it this way. Don't have idea, that is why I ask

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of parameter to 1 outside of your getItems function, then it only gets changed if getItems is called (ie if there's a click).

Inside your function you have:

```
var parametar = object.innerHTML=value;
```

I think you could just write

```
parameter = value;
```